# Expect a 'Type' from third party library functions

Tags: typescript

I'm very new to TypeScript. I've a scenario where I want to assign a type to a variable which's value is returned from a third party libraries's function and it has it own type definition.

For example:

```
import {omit} from 'lodash'

interface ITest {
  a: String;
}

const foo: Object = {
  a: "dfdf",
  b: "sdfsdf",
}

const expected: ITest = omit(foo, 'b')
```

This shows this error

> [ts] Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ITest'.
>
> Property 'a' is missing in type '{}'.

Am I doing it wrong or is it not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `omit` has very few constraints on its return type, and it returns `{}` by default. Take a look at [the definitions for omit](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/56a4356/lodash/lodash.d.ts#L16503-L16506) if you want to dig into this:

```
interface LoDashStatic {
    omit<TResult extends {}, T extends {}>(
        object: T,
        ...predicate: (StringRepresentable|StringRepresentable[])[]
    ): TResult;
}
```

This says that omit has two generic parameters (`TResult` and `T`, which are both at least `{}`). It also has one required parameter (`object`), and 0 or more `predicate`s (strings, more or less). The generic parameter T is the type of its input, and TResult is the overall return type of the function.

When you don't specify generic parameters, TypeScript infers them. These parameters aren't related to each other though, or much else, so it's hard to do that accurately. It can infer `T`: it's the type of the parameter it's given. For `TResult` though, it's got nothing. If you call the function and immediately use the value, in some cases that's enough for inference to work out what the function is expected to return (so what `TResult` is), but in your case it isn't, so it's inferred as `{}`.

Once you've actually called omit in your code, you then try to assign that `{}` to `ITest`, which isn't *definitely* safe - it's possible to get an empty object which doesn't have an `a` property, and this wouldn't be correct.

You have a two options to sort this out:

- Use a type assertion: `const expected = <ITest> omit(foo, 'b')`

  Here you're telling the compiler that you're sure this is an `ITest`. It'll allow that (and give `expected` an `ITest` type), as long as it's *possible* you're correct - you don't have to be *definitely* correct, as you do with the plain assignment.
- Specify the return type for the function by providing the generic parameters that `omit` uses explicitly: `const expected = omit<ITest, {}>(foo, 'b')`.

  Currently these parameters are being inferred automatically, but these type definitions don't have any way to derive the 'correct' type ("the type of foo, but without 'a'"), so you end up with the most general return type possible: `{}`. If you explicitly set those generics, you can control this more closely. You only really want to specify one generic parameter here (the return type), but you can't do that sadly: you have to either specify both, or neither.

Personally I'd use a type assertion, but I think from this point it comes down to a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Well said. What does `{}` in `omit<ITest, {}>(foo, 'b')` mean?

Comment: I've added more detail on the type definitions themselves. There are two generic parameters - TResult and T - and `omit<ITest, {}>(foo, 'b')` sets TResult to ITest and T to {}. TResult is the return type (which is what you want to change), and T is the type of the parameter (foo), which you probably don't care about, but if you want to specify one you have to specify both.